# Page does not display slider on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, slider

for some reason the slider on this website does not display on Google Chrome. I have broken my head finding the issue but I can't seem to find it. I'm thinking it could be a CSS issue? Please help.

http://goo.gl/A6ReWi

This is all I have added to the javascript file and the css file.

s28.postimg.org/7j53s1qcr/stack1.jpg

s28.postimg.org/mql3cei7f/stack2.jpg

Thanks

EDIT***
Thanks for all your help. I figured it out. It was a problem inside the PHP code.

Comment: Can you mention what you have tried so far?

Comment: Would be nice if you provide the CSS and the Javascript related to the slider. Isolate the problem will help you to get better answers.

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome isn't showing a request for the slider images in the Network tab while FF is. I also don't see a `src` attribute on the images in Chrome but do on FF + IE.

Comment: Adrift is right, for some reason the script doesn't set the `src` attribute of the images in Chrome, although it does so in every other browser I tried.

Comment: This is all I have added to the javascript file and the css file.

http://s28.postimg.org/7j53s1qcr/stack1.jpg

http://s28.postimg.org/mql3cei7f/stack2.jpg

Comment: @Adrift what usually causes a problem like that? Could it be inside of the Javascript file or the CSS file? I undid everything and saved the files. Then I cleared cached and it still won't work.

Comment: Do you have unminified code?

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out.